# Gitlab CI pipeline for iOS for Flutter project

Tags: ios, xcode, pipeline, gitlab-ci.yml

I have errors when pushing it to the repo. Error says:

**Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:
variables config should be a hash of key-value pairs
value can be a hash**

What is wrong here?

**The code:**

```
stages:
  - build_android
  - build_ios
  - run_test

variables:
  ver:
    value: "13"
    options:
      - "13"
      - "13.1"
      - "13.2"
      - "13.2.1"
      - "14.0.1"

build_android:
  stage: build_android
  script:
    - flutter build apk

build_ios:
  before_script:
    - export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode_${{ver}}.app/Contents/Developer
  stage: build_ios
  script:
    - xcode-select -s $DEVELOPER_DIR
    - flutter build ios --no-codesign

run_test:
  stage: run_test
  script:
    - flutter test
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the format of the variables section in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. According to the error message, the configuration of variables should be in key-value format, but the given value is in an incorrect format.

To resolve the issue, try changing the format of the ver variable to a key-value pair, like so:

variables:
ver: "13"

not:
variables:
ver:
value: "13"